# Quickfixj - Unsupported Message Type - Execution Report - Fix50 SP2

Tags: java, fix-protocol, quickfixj

I'm seeing the following message when someone send me an execution report:

8=FIXT.1.19=9735=j34=349=XXXXXX52=20210204-10:42:00.29356=XXXXXX45=158=Unsupported Message Type372=8380=310=178

I was expecting to receive the message in one of these methods of my application:

```
@MessageCracker.Handler
 public void onMessage50SP2(quickfix.fix50sp2.ExecutionReport message, SessionId sid){
      //do something
}

@MessageCracker.Handler
 public void onMessage50SP1(quickfix.fix50sp1.ExecutionReport message, SessionId sid){
      //do something
}

@MessageCracker.Handler
 public void onMessage50SP(quickfix.fix50.ExecutionReport message, SessionId sid){
      //do something
}
```

But it seems that none of these methods capture the execution report(35=8) message. I'm using quickfixj 2.1.0
What i'm doing wrong here ?!

Thank you.

Comment: They are also sending you message type y and you reject it. See tag 372 in the Business Message Reject.

Comment: Oh wow, you edited your question with another FIX message now. Now the message is *really* referring to an ExecutionReport.

Comment: yes, it was a mistake, but thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. I had to add another method:

```
 @MessageCracker.Handler
 public void onMessage44(quickfix.fix44.ExecutionReport message, SessionId sid){
      //do something
}
```

And it's working now. But why would quickfixj decide to pick this method instead of the others, since i'm using fix version 5.0 sp2 ?!

Comment: That was impossible to find out with the info that you have given in the question. Are you sure you are using FIX5.0 SP2 **messages** on that session? With FIXT you could send FIX messages for every version. This is specified by the (Default)ApplVerID.

Comment: Sorry, i'm rather new to quickfixj/fx protocol. How could i make sure that i'm using the fix version 5 ? I'm using the ApplVerID = 6 in my cfg and using a fix dictionary for fix 5.0 sp2.

Comment: 5.0 SP2 has ApplVerID = 9. But your counterparty has to support it. Just changing that config won't work if the other side doesn't support it.